# How to convert Canvas to a bitmap image in android?

Tags: android, image, canvas, ondraw

I know this question has been asked before but i am unable to find any solution of my problem.
I tried using the code to create a custom view ,And  i want to create an image from my canvas .
So far i am successfully creating an image, but when it creates an image it appears white screen only now comes  in JPEG format ,as well as in .PNG format.

My Graphiew class is creating a graph and it does a heavy operation on onDraw.

Any suggestion appreciated . Thanks in advance

```
 public class GraphView extends View
{
     Rect r1;
     Rect r2;
     Rect r3;
    static Bitmap bitmap;

     int pixelspercm;

     Paint mPaint;
    private boolean mDoPaint;


    public GraphView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }





    public GraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        init();
    }





    public GraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }




    public void init()
    {
        mPaint=new Paint();
        int density=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;  // for mdpi 160 px

        pixelspercm=(int) (density/2.54f+0.5f);

        setMinimumWidth(25 * pixelspercm);// 1575
    }
    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        // Find out the pixel density
                final float widthScale = pixelspercm / (float)100; // 100 ... 0.63
                // samples per cm
                final float heightScale = (float)328 / pixelspercm; // pixels  328/63=5.2



                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        if(null==r1)
        {
            r1=new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

        }


        if(null==r2)
        {
            r2=new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        }

        if(null==r3)
        {
            r3=new Rect(0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight());

        }

        if(bitmap==null)
        {

            bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(),getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);

        }


        if (null != bitmap && mDoPaint) {// mDoPaint=false
            //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, r1, r2, mPaint);// no execution
            return;
        }

        Paint paint=new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

      // canvas.drawRect(r3,mPaint);

        Paint p=new Paint();
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);



        for(float i=pixelspercm/(float)10;i<getWidth();i=i+pixelspercm/(float) 10)
        {
          canvas.drawLine(i,0,i,getHeight(),p); 
        }



        for(float i=pixelspercm/(float)10;i<getHeight();i=i+pixelspercm/(float) 10)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(0,i,getWidth(),i,p);
        }


        for(int i=pixelspercm;i<getHeight();i=i+pixelspercm)
        {
            p.setStrokeWidth(2);
            canvas.drawLine(0,i,getWidth(),i, p);


        }

        int count=0;
        int y=0;

        // draw 1 cm line for 10 mm/mv

        for(int i=pixelspercm;i<getWidth();i=i+pixelspercm)
        {
            p.setStrokeWidth(2);
            canvas.drawLine(i,0,i,getHeight(),p);

            for (int k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
                y = ((k * 4) * pixelspercm) + 15;  //15,204,393

                canvas.drawText(count + "", i + 2, y,p);// display  1numbers 1 to 24
            }

            count++;
        }




        int mP1 = 0, mPp1 = 0;

        int mP2 = 0, mPp2 = 0;

        int mP3 = 0, mPp3 = 0;

        int mP4 = 0, mPp4 = 0;

        int mP5 = 0, mPp5 = 0;

        int mP6 = 0, mPp6 = 0;

        int mP7 = 0, mPp7 = 0;

        int mP8 = 0, mPp8 = 0;

        int mP9 = 0, mPp9 = 0;

        int mP10 = 0, mPp10 = 0;

        int mP11 = 0, mPp11 = 0;

        int mP12 = 0, mPp12 = 0;

        float mX = mP1 = mP2 = mP3 = 0;
        mP4 = mP5 = mP6 = mP7 = mP8 = mP9 = mP10 = mP11 = mP12 = 0;

        final int graphHeight = pixelspercm;

        float mPx1 = 0;
        mPp1 = 2 * graphHeight;   // 126
        float mPx2 = 0;
        mPp2 = 5 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 2;   315
        float mPx3 = 0;
        mPp3 = 8 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;   504
        float mPx4 = 0;
        mPp4 = 11 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;  693
        float mPx5 = 0;
        mPp5 = 14 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;
        float mPx6 = 0;
        mPp6 = 17 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;
        float mPx7 = 0;
        mPp7 = 20 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;
        float mPx8 = 0;
        mPp8 = 23 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;
        float mPx9 = 0;
        mPp9 = 26 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;
        float mPx10 = 0;
        mPp10 = 29 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;
        float mPx11 = 0;
        mPp11 = 32 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;
        float mPx12 = 0;
        mPp12 = 35 * graphHeight; // graphHeight * 3;

        final int noOfLeads =12;

        final int leadSampleCount = 2500;
        // traverse through the points one by one to get moving graphs
        for (int i = 0; i < PloxXYarray.ecgdata2.length; i++) { // 2500 times 
            if (mX > getWidth()) {
                break;
            }
            mX += widthScale; 

            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

            // draw ECG

            if (noOfLeads >= 1) {
                mP1 = (2 * graphHeight)- (int) ( PloxXYarray.ecgdata1[i] / heightScale);
                canvas.drawLine(mPx1, mPp1, mX, mP1,mPaint);
            }



            // store current point as previous point
                        mPp1 = mP1;
                        mPp2 = mP2;
                        mPp3 = mP3;   
                        mPp4 = mP4;
                        mPp5 = mP5;
                        mPp6 = mP6;
                        mPp7 = mP7;
                        mPp8 = mP8;
                        mPp9 = mP9;
                        mPp10 = mP10;
                        mPp11 = mP11;
                        mPp12 = mP12;
                        mPx1 = mPx2 = mPx3 = mPx4 = mPx5 = mPx6 = mPx7 = mPx8 = mPx9 = mPx10 = mPx11 = mPx12 = mX;


       }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,r1,r2,paint);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        setMeasuredDimension(25*pixelspercm,48*pixelspercm);
    }
```

And this is the code for my MainActivity

```
public class GraphViewActivity extends Activity{
    GraphView graphView;
    Button mSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.graphview);
         graphView=(GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

         mSave=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

         final Paint mPaint=new Paint();
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

         mSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 Bitmap saveMbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(GraphView.bitmap.getWidth(),GraphView.bitmap.getWidth(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                 Canvas canvas=new Canvas(saveMbitmap);
                  canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,GraphView.bitmap.getWidth(),GraphView.bitmap.getHeight()), mPaint);
                 canvas.drawBitmap(GraphView.bitmap, new Rect(0,0,GraphView.bitmap.getWidth(),GraphView.bitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0,0,GraphView.bitmap.getWidth(),GraphView.bitmap.getHeight()), null);




                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "SCREEN_Ecg_MP"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpeg"));
                    saveMbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error--------->", e.toString());
                }
               // canvas.drawBitmap(GraphView.bitmap,r1,r2,mPaint);
            }



        });




    }
```

Comment: Have you made sure you are finding the correct dialog element with `graphView=(GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph)`  maybe you should check to see if `graphView` is `null` before you try to save it. Both jpg's and png's will have file size even if there is just one colour (or transparent) if you are not getting a error then you could be saving null. BTW should you not be using `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` not `Config.ALPHA_8' as you are dropping all the colour info.

Comment: i am using Config.ALPHA_8 to save the memory.As my graphview is drawing a graph and doing heavy operetion. In order to save memory . i am using this , otherwise it will crash with Cinfig.ARGB_8888

Comment: @Blindman67 , you can check my updated question .As grapgView is not null. And it saves an image with white background only